# jsxGraph point update event

Tags: javascript, graph, dom-events

I want to retrieve updated coordinates of a dragable point on **JSXGraph** only when user updates a point coordinates by dragging it. I tried to create a handler for "update" event as follow:

```
var point = board.create('point', [1, 1], {size:0, visible:true, withLabel:false});
point.on('update', function(){console.log('updated', point.X(), point.Y())})
```

However this code doesn't work. The "move" event works, but it is no use to me when I want it for ajax communications. Does anyone know what is the proper event when user drag/updates a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases it should be enough to have an event handler for board. After setting

```
var point = board.create('point', [1, 1], {size:0, visible:true, withLabel:false});
board.on('update', function(){console.log('updated', point.X(), point.Y())});
```

you can call board.update() in the AJAX callback function.